# How to run Rack-based application (not Rails) with Unicorn

Tags: ruby, rack, unicorn

How can I run a Rack-based application (not Rails) with unicorn? Let's assume I have a "hello world" response simple rack app with the name of `server.ru`, and config file at the same directory with the name of `unicorn.conf`, how am I supposed to run it? In Thin, for example, I would do something like:

```
bundle exec rackup server.ru -s thin -E production -p 4001
```

How would I do the same to run under Unicorn?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unicorn does not give any special treatment to Rails 3+ applications, so the behavior is exactly the same for Rails 3+ applications and non-Rails Rack applications. Just run

```
unicorn
```

in your app's root. To run with a specific port, pass `-p/--port` with the port:

```
unicorn -p 4001
```

You can also specify the rackup file:

```
unicorn server.ru
```

You can see all the options by running `unicorn --help`. Of course, you should prepend `bundle exec` to these commands as needed by your setup.

Comment: but how am I supposed to specify the file ? in this case server.ru ?

Comment: @EkiEqbal Updated. But again, *this is all in unicorn's help*. Read it, it's useful and worth your time.

Comment: For the obtuse, unicorn docs: [launcher](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/unicorn_1.html), [config](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html). [Rack](https://github.com/rack/rack)

Answer (score 3):

You can make a setting file for unicorn like this:

```
working_directory "/path/to/your/app"
listen 4001
pid "/tmp/unicorn.pid"
```

And then launch unicorn with the following command:

```
unicorn -c /path/to/your/setting/file.rb
```